Use defined operators from base class in inherited class
Assume I have a base class
class Vector
{
public:
    Vector(const std::vector<float> &elements);

    static Vector add(const Vector &v1, const Vector &v2);

    Vector Vector::operator+(const Vector &v) const
    {
        return add(*this, v);
    }

    Vector &Vector::operator+=(const Vector &v)
    {
        *this = add(*this, v);
        return *this;
    }

    float operator[](size_t index) const;

private:
    std::vector<float> _elements;
}


And a derived class for a 3 element vector:
class Vector3 : public Vector
{
public:
    Vector3(float x, float y, float z);
};

What would I have to do to use the operators with the derived class?
My solution was to redefine the operators in the derived class like so:
Vector3 Vector3::operator+(const Vector3 &v) const
{
    Vector res = Vector::operator+(v);
    return Vector3(res[0], res[1], res[2]);
}

Vector3 &Vector3::operator+=(const Vector3 &v)
{
    Vector res = Vector::operator+=(v);
    *this = Vector3(res[0], res[1], res[2]);
    return *this;
}

That works so far, but I was wondering if this is the right way to go. For me it looks a lot like double work. Furthermore I don't fully understand why I even have to redefine the operators in the first place. Is it because I can't cast from Vector to Vector3? My simple assumption was Vector3 is the same as Vector with size 3, so in my mind there isn't a difference that would be relevant for the given operator task to be different. If someone could enlighten me whether there is a better approach that would be great.

Having a type with a fixed number of items (Vector3) be derived from a type with a dynamic number of items (Vector) seems like bad idea to me.

Can you elaborate further? I have the base class for a n-dimensional Vector which implements addition, dot product, norm etc and later classes like Vector3 that implement more functionality like cross product, angles etc and Quaternions as a 4-dimensional type with different multiplication rules and so on. I was doing a lot of double work when it came to the basic calculations.

@KompjoeFriek is right. You've added unnecessary pointer-chasing and cache-misses in addition to the overhead needded to track a variable-sized container. Consider making Vector a template where at least one template argument is the size of the container. That allow you to use a simpler fixed size container like std::array in the back end AND turn Vector3 into a typedef (eg using Vector3 = Vector<3>;, giving you exactly the behaviour you want without inheritance complicating things.

Side note: consider ditching the add method. Do the adding in += and make + a free function. Much wisdom about operator overloading can be found here

Vectors used for 2D, 3D and 4D math operations are almost universally implemented as trivial types for good reason. They should not allocate and thhey should not have virtual methods.

Even if you could expose the base operators in the derived class, why would you want to? That would allow variable-length vectors to be added to your fixed-length vector. What would you want to do if the sizes don't match?

For 3 elements, I would create my own class, similar to a 3D point class.

class Vector3 : public Vector - this inheritance breaks Liskov substitution principle.

"What would I have to do to use the operators with the derived class?" -- Nothing. Why do you think it doesn't work as-is? Note: if you're looking for an operator that returns a Vector3 instead of a Vector then you are not looking for the same operator. This would be a solvable problem, but it warrants more description in your question.

Frame challenge: What you want to do here adds complexity, inheritance and the hoops (practical and conceptual) you have to jump through because of it, and reduces performance1. That's the kiss of death trade-off. Since you generally only want to suffer increased complexity in order to get increased performance, do something else.
My suggestion, keeping most of what you had in mind is to

Turn Vector into a template, with the size being a template argument (and potentially the data type stored so you can easily switch between floats, doubles, and ints)
Turn Vector3 into a typedef. eg using Vector3 = Vector<3>;. Now Vector3 literaly is a Vector so there is no need for wresting with inheritance while providing exactly the behaviour you want.
Make the operator overloading a bit more idiomatic.

Here is a quick demo:
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template<size_t SIZE> // A more general <class TYPE, int SIZE> will be more useful
class Vector
{
public:
    // initializer_list may make this easier to work with
    Vector(const std::array<float,SIZE> &elements): _elements(elements)
    {

    }

    Vector & operator+=(const Vector &v)
    {
        //just crapping out a simple summation here for demo purposes
        std::transform(_elements.begin(), _elements.end(),
                       v._elements.begin(),
                       _elements.begin(),
                       std::plus());
        return *this;
    }

    float operator[](size_t index) const;
    // consider adding the usual iterator -granting functions so 
    // you can use one of these in Standard algorithms

    // added for demo purposes to print out the result
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out,
                                     const Vector & vec)
    {
        for (const auto & val:vec._elements)
        {
            out << val << ' ';
        }
        return out;
    }

private:
    std::array<float, SIZE> _elements; // Look ma! No pointers! 
                                       // The Vector data is IN the Vector!
                                       // no extra look-ups and no extra 
                                       // cache misses
};


// now a free function to aid in decoupling 
template <size_t SIZE>
Vector<SIZE> operator+(Vector<SIZE> lhs, 
                       const Vector<SIZE> &rhs)
{
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
}

using Vector3 = Vector<3>;

int main()
{
    Vector3 a({1,2,3});
    Vector3 b({3,2,1});
    Vector3 c = a+b;

    std::cout << c << '\n';

    Vector<4> d({});

    //Vector3 e = c+d; // addition fails at compile time because the types 
                       // don't match. Much debug savings
}

1 std::vector points at its data, so the CPU almost always has to read the Vector and the vector data separately.
For a small amount of data that could have been read in one shot, this can be an utterly murderous performance hit.

Thank you very much, I will try to follow this approach.
